# Cucumber cannot follow simple link, cannot find path method in Rack Request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, cucumber

I have spent a few hours on this, I have the following simple feature:

```
Feature: New User Registration

  Scenario: A user should be able to create a new account
    Given I am on the homepage
    When I follow "My Account"
```

and when I run it using

```
cucumber features/authentication.feature
```

lines 33-36 of web-steps looks like:

```
When /^(?:|I )follow "([^"]*)"(?: within "([^"]*)")?$/ do |link, selector|
  with_scope(selector) do
    click_link(link)
  end
end
```

I get the following errors:

```
/Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/actionpack-2.3.2/lib/action_controller/vendor/rack-1.0/rack.rb:17: warning: already initialized constant VERSION
```

AND

> .F
>
> (::) failed steps (::)
>
> undefined method `path' for #<Rack::Request:0x10577bf40>
>   (NoMethodError) (eval):2:in`send' (eval):2:in `click_link'
>   ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:35
>   ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:14:in`with_scope'
>   ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:34:in `/^(?:|I )follow
>   "([^"]*)"(?: within "([^"]*)")?$/'
>   features/authentication.feature:5:in`When I follow "My Account"'

I'm using Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 2.3.2, Capybara 1.1.1 and cucumber-rails 0.3.2

Any help is much appreciated, pulling my hair out over this one! :)

**UPDATE**

I fixed this by downgrading capybara to 1.0.1, uninstalling cucumber & reinstalling and it worked. Hope this can help someone else.

Comment: what does the code look like in web_steps.rb? maybe the code block that contains line 35?

Comment: OP updated to include lines 33-36

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by downgrading capybara to 1.0.1, uninstalling cucumber & reinstalling and it worked. Hope this can help someone else.